# Class of 16 Participants Answering 6 Questions in Subsets of 4, Each One in A Different Combination With All Pairings Covered

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

16 Participants are arranged into 4 groups of 4. The participants work together on a question within their groups. Next the groups are rearranged into another 4 groups of 4, where they work on the second question, and so on for six questions. Each participant must work with every other participant at least once at some point in the exercise.

Is this possible? If not, how can you prove that it is impossible. If it is possible, what are the six configurations of the participants?

The initial configuration of the 16 participants into groups A, B, C & D is:

A: 1, 2, 3, 4

B: 5, 6, 7, 8

C: 9, 10, 11, 12

D: 13, 14, 15, 16

Comment: There are 120 possible pairings to cover, and each group of 4 provides 6 of these. Does that mean that after 5 questions, all pairings should be possible?

Comment: Choosing 4 groups of 4 from 16 can be done in 63,063,000 ways - a multinomial number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a variant of the "social golfer problem", but there you want each pair to be together at most once.

1. 1-2-3-4, 5-6-7-8, 9-10-11-12, 13-14-15-16
2. 1-5-9-13, 2-6-10-14, 3-7-11-15, 4-8-12-16
3. 1-6-11-16, 2-5-12-15, 3-8-9-14, 4-7-10-13
4. 1-7-12-14, 2-8-11-13, 3-5-10-16, 4-6-9-15
5. 1-8-10-15, 2-7-9-16, 3-6-12-13, 4-5-11-14

So after five sessions, every pair has worked together exactly once, so you can do whatever you like for the sixth session.

This was taken from "four groups of four golfers for five weeks" at [http://web.archive.org/web/20050407074608/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/~wh/golf/solutions.html#4-4-5](http://web.archive.org/web/20050407074608/http://www.icparc.ic.ac.uk/%7Ewh/golf/solutions.html#4-4-5)

Comment: Many thanks for this. I was at a bit of a loss as to how to characterise the problem for an internet search! Now I know, "The Social Golfers Problem"!!